# Electrical energy to negative thermal energy

Tags: thermodynamics, thermoelectricity

Most devices that require cooling either use an active (fan) or passive (heat sink / coolant) system to reduce temperature, which require a relatively large surface area to be effective.

Are there any simple techniques to instantly cool a small object with electricity on a small scale?

My understanding is that you can generate heat by simply shorting a battery. Is there no inverse to this to "generate cold"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use a *peltier effect thermojunction device* which generates cold and heat when electric current passes through it. These devices are used in so-called "solid state refrigerators" that are sold to keep food and drinks cold in, for example, a car (where they are designed to run on 12 volts DC).

They are nowhere near as efficient as mechanical heat pumps as used in household refrigerator/freezers but are extremely simple and compact.